# Adaptive questionform on Mechanical Turk (boto)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I would like to create a question form where a person needs to click on a link and rate a website. However, the link might be broken. I had thought of first asking the worker whether the link is visible, and if yes, then ask about the rating. Is this feasible? I am using the python library boto.

Answer (score 0):

QuestionForm is not dynamic in this way. You should instead use the HTMLQuestion structure and use javascript to dynamically parse the answer to the first question and conditionally show the second.